# How to mock creation of ServletFileUpload using PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I want to test that in a certain class an instance of ServletFileUpload class is created.

This is the class being tested:

```
public class ClassBeingTested {
    public void run()
    {
        new ServletFileUpload();
    }
}
```

And this is the test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ServletFileUpload.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testServletUploadCreation() throws Exception {
        // Setup mock
        final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = createMockAndExpectNew(
                ServletFileUpload.class);
        replay(fileUpload, ServletFileUpload.class);

        // Invoke method under test
        final ClassBeingTested objectUnderTest = new ClassBeingTested();
        objectUnderTest.run();

        // Verify that ServletFileUpload instance was created
        verify(fileUpload, ServletFileUpload.class);
    }

}
```

The `verify` statement throws following exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload(): expected: 1, 
      actual: 0
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.NewInvocationControlAssertionError.throwAssertionErrorForNewSubstitutionFailure(NewInvocationControlAssertionError.java:21)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verifyClass(PowerMock.java:2279)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify(PowerMock.java:1646)
    at MyTest.testServletUploadCreation(MyTest.java:21)
```

Why? And how can I fix it?

Note that [this way](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) of mocking constructors works in other places of my code.

Comment: What are you testing? That the jvm actually constructs an object when you call  `new ServletFileUpload();` ?

Comment: The code snippet is part of a larger test. In the actual code, class being tested creates a new instance of ServletFileUpload and then invokes some methods of it. I want to mock the return value of these methods.

Comment: Then I would change the design of this class so that `new` is not called in the run method and is more easily mockable.

Comment: Sure. I know about the factory pattern. The problem is that when you do it, you may end up with lots of boilerplate code (I'm talking from experience). So I'm experimenting with PowerMock in order to find out, how to write testable code without many factories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to change this line `@PrepareForTest(ServletFileUpload.class)` to `@PrepareForTest(ClassBeingTested.class)`